# Calculate arc parameters between two given points (x,y)

Tags: trigonometry

say i have two points (x,y) (10,10) and (100,100) how would i be able to calculate the width, height, startAngle and arcAngle (parameters for java.awt.graphics#drawArc), to draw an arc between those two points?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. There is an infinite number of circles that pass through two points. You need more information, such as the radius (you will get two solutions), or the center of the circle (1 or 0 solutions) or another point on the arc

Comment: so if 3 points are known, how would it be done then?

Comment: Yes. If the three points are not colinear, they will form a triangle. You can look up circumscribed circle (it's unique) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Triangles